# Word to explain how you feel when your expectations are subverted

Tags: single-word-requests

**Context:** I would like to talk about how a book questions the reader's traditional, conservative values about family structures. I want to say we are introduced to a shared household wherein there isn't a typical nuclear family structure, the children are not trained in table manners and everything is loud, lively and disorganised. This contrasts the presumed reader (at the time)'s traditional beliefs that a house should have a nuclear family, children should be taught table manners, etc.

The sentence I want to say is, "The reader is positioned to feel [insert word], as their beliefs are subverted and challenged."

**Words I've tried so far:**

- Unsettled
- Uneasy
- Disturbed

These are the closest words I could find but I feel like they have a more negative association, and creates a malaise in the reader. I feel that the effect of the book is more subtle and just lightly 'shocks' the reader, positioning them to just take notice of their preconceived beliefs, rather than evoke a negative reaction.

- Destabilise
- Bewildered

These words suggest that the representation of these households are completely weird and confusing, however, that is not the case. It's not so weird that a reader wouldn't comprehend it, these households are just *different* to the mainstream households.

Source for definitions: Google dictionary

Comment: Would "surprised" work? Something which is not expected happens.

Comment: *Unsettling* or *disturbing* are commonly used for art which challenges or disturbs the viewer; it's only a negative thing if you don't want art to be challenging. (Googling *unsettling art* etc will give a lot of examples)

Comment: How about "jarred" or "jolted"? I don't think these have a necessarily negative connotation, and they work well with adverbs like "somewhat", if you're willing to use those.

Comment: what about "disconcerted" (*which implies an upsetting of equanimity or assurance producing uncertainty or hesitancy*) ?

Comment: You've already answered the question with *The sentence I want to say is...* The books you're talking about are ***challenging***. That's challenging to *your* prior belief systems, but I don't know if you're really the target audience for the work anyway - it might be just an everyday tale of everyday folk to some readers.

Comment: *disoriented*...

Comment: untethered, upended

Comment: Searching for a single-word might be enough to bring the Question from Writing to EL&U. I see the particular example as too flimsy to ring true. At least in the West, '… a shared household wherein there isn't a typical nuclear family structure, the children are not trained in table manners and everything is loud, lively and disorganised…' is far too common to be noteworthy, let alone invoke anything suggested in the Question, Comments or Answer. Further, isn't 'subverted' an odd fit for 'expectations'?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.merriam-webster.com/

Dismayed: experiencing or showing feelings of alarmed concern or dismay : upset, worried, or agitated because of some unwelcome situation or occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered "[enlightened](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/enlightened)" or "[illuminated](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/illuminate)" if you would like positive connotations? Or maybe a two word phrase using something like "acutely" would do better: eg. "acutely jarred", "acutely disturbed" or "acutely disrupted".

As a note; upon verifying the definition of acutely, it seems to be defined as "[completely or extremely](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/acutely)". However, in my experience it can refer to something that is nuanced and requires perception. This is backed up by one of Google's definitions being "[in a way that shows a perceptive understanding or insight](https://www.google.com/search?q=acutely%20definition)". A less ambiguous word might be "[subtly](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/subtly)" but it lacks the connotations of a broadening world view.

The word "[exposed](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/exposed)" can be defined as "uncovered so that it can be seen" and seems to give the intended feel, but I'm not sure how you'd work it into your sentence without a restructuring.

[note, have just read another comment and "challenged" seems suitable too]